# how to replace windows carriage return with a space in a ginormous text file

Tags: unix

The file size in question is 60 GB (don't ask why). I need to replace the windows carraige return rather quickly. Any one care to share (voodo unix skills welcome)

Edit: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244115/linux-command-to-replace-string-in-large-file-with-another-string)  stackoverflow question helpful as well, but I think this could be even large for sed to produce a result in time (let's see I will report back)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply do

```
cat file | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: windows carraige return looks like ^M in unix and not really a \n

Comment: Usually \r\n is the fill line feed from windows, \n should be the right one as \r is usually the linux/mac line feeds.

Answer (score 3):

Try this on a smaller version of the file first to be sure its ok

```
sed "s/\r//" infile >outfile
```

Comment: I was considering Sed, but this would take ages. The system is a QuadCore Xeon and I don't mind a bit of hacking as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following should work:

```
cat file | tr -d '\015' > file1
```